# Unit test Observable with delay operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a hard time getting my unit test to work together with an Observable with delay operator. The application is built on Angular 2 and the tests are running in karma/jasmine. I've tried the async and fakeAsync helper methods but none of them are working.

Here's a simplified code block (without Angular 2) explaining my issue.

```
let mouseDownStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'mousedown');
let haveBeenCalled = false;
mouseDownStream.delay(200).subscribe(() => haveBeenCalled = true);

describe('mouse down event', () => {
  it('it should emit an event stream after 200ms', (done) => {
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))
    expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeFalsy();

    // Don't want this setTimeout should use Angular's tick(200) method instead but it's not working.
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    }, 200)
  });
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yocayibuqi/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Are you getting some error like "can't call setInterval inside async zone"? If so, from what I remember, I don't think it's possible. What you're doing is the best way

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with the above example. Tests are passing. I just don't want to use the set timeout for all my tests.

Comment: No, I mean are you getting that error with async and fakeAsync

Comment: No, no errors. If I would use the above example with fakeAsync or async methods haveBeenCalled will never be truthy even tho I call tick(1000) before the assertion

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example on how to unit test an Observable with a delay operator in Angular 2+, should anyone still be looking for the answer:

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

describe("mouse down event", () => {
  it("should emit an event stream after 200ms", fakeAsync(() => {
    let mouseDownStream = fromEvent(document.body, "mousedown");
    let haveBeenCalled = false;

    const subscription = mouseDownStream.pipe(delay(200)).subscribe(() => (haveBeenCalled = true));
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown"));

    expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeFalsy();

    tick(200);

    expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();

    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using rxjs 6 with angular 12, `fakeAsync` doesn't work for me.  Only using the `TestScheduler` did.  Modifying Ritchie's sample:

```
describe("mouse down event", () => {
    let testScheduler: TestScheduler;
    beforeEach(() => {
      testScheduler = new TestScheduler((act, exp) => expect(exp).toEqual(act) as any);      
    });

    fit("should emit an event stream after 200ms", () => {
      let mouseDownStream = fromEvent(document.body, "mousedown");
      let haveBeenCalled = false;
  
      testScheduler.run(() => {
        const subscription = mouseDownStream.pipe(delay(200)).subscribe(() => (haveBeenCalled = true));
        document.body.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown"));
        expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeFalsy();
        testScheduler.createTime('200|');
        testScheduler.flush();
        expect(haveBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      });
    });
});
```